# Kafka Python - Consumer

Tags: python, apache-kafka, consumer

I have issues using my Python Consumer.

Below is the sample code that I have used to learn how to use python Kafka and it work.

**Producer.py**

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                         value_serializer=lambda x: 
                         dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))

for e in range(1000):
    data = {'number' : e}
    producer.send('numtest', value=data)
    sleep(5)
```

**consumer.py**

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'numtest',
     bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
     auto_offset_reset='earliest',
     enable_auto_commit=True,
     group_id='my-group',
     value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')))

for message in consumer:
    message = message.value
```

However, I change the codes to suit my needs and my consumer does not work anymore (with no error).

**project_producer.py**

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                         value_serializer=lambda x:dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))

while True:
    Speed = fetch_all("http://datamall2.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice/TrafficSpeedBandsv2")
    SpeedS = Speed[0:2]
    #now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
    for road in SpeedS:
        producer.send('testing', value=road)
        producer.flush()
        print(f"Sending road to Kafka: {road}")
    sleep(300)
```

Sample of Output
[image: Sample of Output (Producer)]

**project_consumer.py**

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'testing',
     bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
     auto_offset_reset=None,
     enable_auto_commit=True,
     group_id='hi',
     consumer_timeout_ms=1000,
     value_deserializer=lambda x: loads(x.decode('utf-8')))

for message in consumer:
    print ("Message", message)
    if message is not None:
        print (message.offset, message.value)

print ("Quit")
```

let me know if you have ideas on how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I believe this line is causing issue here

```
auto_offset_reset=None
```

If your intension is to read messages produced by producer after consumer starts then you should put your consume loop in another loop like you did with your producer.

```
while True:
    for message in consumer:
        print ("Message", message)
        if message is not None:
            print (message.offset, message.value)
    # You can put your stop event here. ( like after 1 hour break infinite loop and be done with consumer.)
```

Note: When you use **auto_offset_reset=None** it will throw exception to the consumer if no previous offset is found for the consumer's group. you should handle exception properly in your code. (or use **earliest** or **latest**)